# How to dump dict values with curly braces to JSON using json.dumps?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to encode dict objects like this using `json.dumps`.

```
json_str = json.dumps({'test':'/inform{"payload"}'})
```

But this seems to add a backslash after the brace.

```py
print(json_str)
# '{"test": "/inform{\\"payload\\"}"}'

print(repr(json_str))
# '\'{"test": "/inform{\\\\"payload\\\\"}"}\''
```

I'm pretty puzzled that it does this only within the brackets.

Comment: It adds a backlash *before the quote*, not after the brace. Because otherwise the double quote would end the string. It's working correctly, what's the *problem*?

Answer (score 0):

It's working correctly, but it's sometimes a bit confusing when escaping is escaped.

```py
>>> import json
>>> json_str = json.dumps({'test':'/inform{"payload"}'})
>>> json_str
'{"test": "/inform{\\"payload\\"}"}'
>>> print(json_str)
{"test": "/inform{\"payload\"}"}
```

`{"test": "/inform{\"payload\"}"}` is the correct JSON as the double quotes need to be escaped.  When you just run `json_str` above it outputs the string representation of that so it has to escape the `\` into `\\` and puts the whole thing in single quotes.  When you did `print(repr(json_str))` you're again escaping the escaped string.